# Moving a Car the quickest path

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have a car, that has a current angle and location, and a destination angle and location. The car has a maximum linear and angular acceleration. Assume the car will always travel in the direction it is facing. I'm trying to figure out how to determine the path that this car should travel that will be the quickest path. An example setup might be as follows:

[image]

The car has to end up in the direction and location of the rightmost arrow, and is facing the direction of the leftmost.

What I'm trying to do is to figure out the optimal path, or at least a reasonable approximation of the optimal path, that will get between the two points. Assume an empty field, the car can travel over anything without restriction. The car might be moving beforehand as well.

Ultimately, I'm trying to figure out the formula that will take the current state and the destination state and figure out what the next step should be.

Comment: Do you know about optimal control theory? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control/. I think that's the formal solution to your problem. The most important take-away is that the solution will, most likely, be one with bang-bang control (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang%E2%80%93bang_control), i.e. your driver will always be full on the gas and the breaks and make the largest possible steering motions that are possible without losing traction.

Comment: That sounds about right. Hmmm...

Comment: Would the brachistochrone curve 'in reverse' work? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=li-an5VUrIA